# Writing Shorter Code Javascript using

Tags: javascript

//Im new to functional programming what would be the best way to write this using functional programming.

```
    var SQUARE_X = 101,
        SQUARE_Y = 83;

// function to detect the enemy collison
    function collisionDetect(axisA, axisB) {
        var playerX = Math.floor(axisA.x / SQUARE_X);
        var playerY = Math.floor(axisA.y / SQUARE_Y);
        if (Array.isArray(axisB)) {
            for (var i = 0; i < axisB.length; i += 1) {
                var enemyX = Math.floor(axisB[i].x / SQUARE_X);
                var enemyY = Math.floor((axisB[i].y) / SQUARE_Y);
                if (enemyX === playerX && enemyY === playerY) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            var enemyX = Math.floor(axisB.x / SQUARE_X);
            var enemyY = Math.floor((axisB.y) / SQUARE_Y);
            if (enemyX === playerX && enemyY === playerY) {
                return true;
            }
        }

    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean about `functional`, but if you just want to refactor your code, here is some clue:

```
var SQUARE_X = 101,
    SQUARE_Y = 83;

// function to detect the enemy collison
function collisionDetect(axisA, axisB) {
    var playerX = Math.floor(axisA.x / SQUARE_X);
    var playerY = Math.floor(axisA.y / SQUARE_Y);

    return ([].concat(axisB)).some(function(ab) {
        var enemyX = Math.floor(ab.x / SQUARE_X);
        var enemyY = Math.floor(ab.y / SQUARE_Y);
        if (enemyX === playerX && enemyY === playerY) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

The benefits here are that the code is shorter, the login is placed in 1 place only, so if you have to change it it is easy.

Not sure why you need functional here.